# Jackal simulation in ROS kinetic - getting the error: bash: cd: jackal_ws: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, simulation, ros, robotics

I'm trying to simulate the Jackal via ROS Kinetic on Gazebo following this tutorial, https://gist.github.com/vfdev-5/57a0171d8f5697831dc8d374839bca12

I have done the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot-localization ros-kinetic-controller-manager ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins             ros-kinetic-lms1xx ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-description ros-kinetic-roslint ros-kinetic-amcl ros-kinetic-gmapping      ros-kinetic-map-server ros-kinetic-move-base ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-xacro ros-kinetic-message-runtime ros-kinetic-topic-tools ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy
```

and

```
mkdir -p jackal_ws/src; cd jackal_ws/src; catkin_init_workspace
git clone https://github.com/jackal/jackal.git
git clone https://github.com/jackal/jackal_simulator.git
git clone https://github.com/jackal/jackal_desktop.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/interactive_marker_twist_server.git
```

After the above step, I got:

```
bash: cd: jackal_ws: No such file or directory
```

Then, I did the next step below:

```
cd jackal_ws; catkin_make; source devel/setup.bash
```

After the above step, I got:

```
bash: cd: jackal_ws: No such file or directory  
Base path: /home/USER/jackal_ws/src  
The specified source space "/home/USER/jackal_ws/src/src" does not exist   
bash: devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

What have I done wrong?

---

I redid the steps separately, and here is what I get in the terminal:

user@user:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot-localization ros-kinetic-controller-manager ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins             ros-kinetic-lms1xx ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-description ros-kinetic-roslint ros-kinetic-amcl ros-kinetic-gmapping      ros-kinetic-map-server ros-kinetic-move-base ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-xacro ros-kinetic-message-runtime ros-kinetic-topic-tools ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy

[sudo] password for user:

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

user@user:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

user@user:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process

user@user:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot-localization ros-kinetic-controller-manager ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins             ros-kinetic-lms1xx ros-kinetic-pointgrey-camera-description ros-kinetic-roslint ros-kinetic-amcl ros-kinetic-gmapping      ros-kinetic-map-server ros-kinetic-move-base ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-xacro ros-kinetic-message-runtime ros-kinetic-topic-tools ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

user@user:~$ mkdir -p jackal_ws/src

user@user:~$ cd jackal_ws/src

user@user:~/jackal_ws/src$ catkin_init_workspace

File "/home/user/jackal_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" already

existsuser@user:~/jackal_ws/src$ git clone

https://github.com/jackal/jackal.

fatal: destination path 'jackal' already exists and is not an empty directory.

user@user:~/jackal_ws/src$ git clone

https://github.com/jackal/jackal_simulator.git

fatal: destination path 'jackal_simulator' already exists and is not an empty directory.

user@user:~/jackal_ws/src$ git clone

https://github.com/jackal/jackal_desktop.git

fatal: destination path 'jackal_desktop' already exists and is not an empty directory.

user@user:~/jackal_ws/src$ git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/interactive_marker_twist_server.git

fatal: destination path 'interactive_marker_twist_server' already exists and is not an empty directory.

user@user:~/jackal_ws/src$ cd jackal_ws

bash: cd: jackal_ws: No such file or directory

Comment: This is not a user friendly tutorial because the second "step" is actually 7 commands with no error handling. Can you try it again, but with each command separately (e.g. `mkdir -p jackal_ws/src `, then 
 afterwards `cd jackal_ws/src`, then `catkin_init_workspace`) and STOP IMMEDIATELY if you get any error message from any of them? Then post the complete terminal transcript including the commands you ran and the output or errors from each of them.

Comment: @thatotherguy, okay, I'll do that now! I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @thatotherguy, I redid the steps, but after the line (cd jackal_ws), I get the error: bash: cd: jackal_ws: No such file or directory.

Comment: After step 2 you would be in the directory `jackal_ws/src`. You can use `cd ..` instead to go back up to `jackal_ws`. Use `pwd` to verify that you are in the right directory. Then `catkin_make`

Comment: By after step 2, do you mean mkdir -p jackal_ws/src? Also, I edited my post and put what I got in my terminal above!

Comment: I meant it as the whole thing the way the tutorial described it. Just `cd ..` where you are right now, or equivalently, `cd ~/jackal_ws` from anywhere

Comment: This removed the errors I was getting, thanks! Now, when I run the last line of code from the tutorial (to start the simulation - this is the code: roslaunch jackal_viz view_robot.launch), I get: `[view_robot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [jackal_viz] nor is [jackal_viz] is a launch file name. The traceback for the exception was written to the log file.` What do I do?